# Perform some asp.net mvc server side code depending on screen resolution

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to load google ad-sense based on screen resolution in asp.net mvc

I have write below code in view

```
<div class="buyer_banner">
                @if (!isMobile)
                {
                    <div class="mobile-portrait-hide">
                        @Html.Raw(searchBanner.AdSenseCode)
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="mobile-portrait-show">
                        @Html.Raw(searchBanner.AdSenseCode)
                   </div>
                }
            </div>
```

i need to set isMobile flag based on screen resolution, currently i have used user agent

Answer (score 0):

From the server-side, the only mechanism built into the framework is in [the HttpCompatibilitiesBase class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
```

This is not guaranteed to be accurate; that's where [51 degrees project on github](https://github.com/51Degrees/dotNET-Device-Detection) or [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) paid licenses come into play, for a might higher degree of accuracy.